# Recursive background process on cpanel server

Tags: time, server, cpanel

Aim:
Hi I have made a php scraper and want to scrape a website every 10 minutes (by running the php script).

Problem:
I am using cpanel and unsure how to create a background process like that unless I have a browser open on a different machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cPanel cron jobs:

**1.** To access the Cron Jobs Menu, click on the corresponding icon located on the main screen of your cPanel interface.

**2.** Specify the absolute path to the command that you wish to run. For example, if you wish to run the public_html/index.php file in your home directory, enter the following command:

```
/home/user/public_html/index.php
```

To disable notifications for a specific cron job, add the following line to the command:

```
>/dev/null 2>&1
```

**3.** Select how often you wish the command to be run by selecting an option in each of the boxes or by selecting a predefined period from the Common Settings drop-down menu.

> You **must** specify settings for the Minute, Hour, Day, Month, Weekday,
>   and Command text boxes.

**4.** Click on `Add New Cron Job` to save your changes and set up your cron job.